# Hibernate cannot merge and persist two instances of entity class

Tags: java, hibernate

When I try to update `Team` Hibernate throws exception:

```
    Multiple representations of the same entity [Team#1] are being merged.
 Detached: [Team@49a0aef3]; Managed: [Team@bf505c]
```

**TeamDAOImpl**

```
    public void updateTeam(Team team) {
            Team teamToUpdate = getTeam(team.getId());
            teamToUpdate.setName(team.getName());
            team = null; // doesn't help to avoid exception
            getCurrentSession().merge(teamToUpdate);
        }
    public Team getTeam(int id) {
        Team team = (Team) getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, id);
        return team;
    }
```

I have seen most issues related to this exception but haven't found solution that works. How to fix it?

**Update:**

It seems to be some kind of [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9106) the Hibernate team had to fix. In my case the logic is extremely trivial, I cannot believe Hibernate unable to update current entity. There has to be a way.

Comment: I think getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, id) point the same object with a different location. Try to create a new instance of team, as follow: Team team = new Team(); and tell me

Comment: I don't understand the point

Comment: In getTeam method, instead Team team = (Team) getCurrentSession().get(Team.class, id); write: Team team = new Team();

Comment: same error occurs after changes

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by removing *CascadeType* from source entity.

Comment: I spent hours trying to solve this problem. Thank you for the hint.